# Parameters from .jsf requests changes every time there is change in build. How can we avoid this maintenance?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jmeter

My application has .jsf requests and in post data there are few parameters as below:

"j_id_jsp_457390_**0**" , "results_form:j_id_jsp_457390_**167**" [in both Name & Value column]

Now the issue is whenever there is a change in build or change in environment parameters etc., last number is changing i.e. **0** and **167**. And because of this, need to adapt the scripts again wherein we need to invest more than 2 weeks efforts.

I have tried xpath extractor but it is not working everywhere, specially in Name column of parameters tab.

Could someone let me know about the solution of this or may be how these id's getting generated?

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

So, you have input components without an ID like below.

```
<h:form id="results_form">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" />
```

Just explicitly specify the ID yourself in the `id` attribute of the component in question instead of relying on an autogenerated one.

```
<h:form id="results_form">
    <h:inputText id="some_input" value="#{bean.value}" />
```

The client ID will become `results_form:some_input` this way. Permanently.

In case you're using JSF 2.2+, the [OmniFaces `NoAutoGeneratedViewHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/viewhandlers/NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler) may be helpful in this during development. By the way, JSP is deprecated and replaced by Facelets since JSF 2.0. Consider migrating.

Comment: Thanks. could you please elaborate more on this. As i have mentioned i have below parameters:"j_id_jsp_457390_0" , "results_form:j_id_jsp_457390_167" [in both Name & Value column]. Now what should I mentioned at the palce of 0 and 167 so that even if the value changes my script should work.

Comment: I updated the answer to point out the real problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the way of dynamically obtaining some form generated IDs you can do it via [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as:

```
    import org.apache.jmeter.util.XPathUtil;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    Document document = XPathUtil.makeDocument(in, false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false);

    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//input/@id | //input[@type='hidden']");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
      log.info("Input " + i + " ID = " + nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```

For instance, for [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) website the output will be:

```
2015/04/13 17:34:32 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Input 0 ID = search_form_input_homepage 
2015/04/13 17:34:32 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Input 1 ID = search_button_homepage 
2015/04/13 17:34:32 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Input 2 ID = search_form_input_clear
```

If you need to provide values you can use [Arguments.addArgument()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html#addArgument(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method. See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide to learn more on scripting in Apache JMeter.

If the answer is not what you're looking for, try elaborating your query providing as much details as possible.

Comment: Hi, this is useful. But my test plan has 450 users with 50 different scripts. And no of such elements are more than 3500 in 50 scripts. And iteration in most of the scripts are 50 or so. So if I use this solution then it should affect on the statistics of test.  Please suggest.

Comment: PostProcessors aren't being included into sampler time (as well as preprocessors and timers) unless you are using [Transaction Controller](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)

Comment: Yes, I am using Transaction Controller for each step in the script. Now what is the other way round for this issue?